# Is my Hashtable created in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, hashtable, big-o

I am trying to create a Hashtable in OCaml in O(n) time (n being the length of a string).

Here is my code:

```
let fill_table set my_hash = 
  for i = 0 to ((String.length set) - 1) do
    Hashtbl.add my_hash (Char.code set.[i]) (set.[i])
  done
;;
```

where set is a string (ex/ "12345") and my_hash is previously initiated as:

```
let my_hash = Hashtbl.create 255 (* Highest ASCII number possible *)
```

Does 'fill_table' function run in O(n) time? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you add the condition that all characters in the string are unique (otherwise your code makes even less sense) then this code runs in O(1) since n <= 256 limits your problem and makes O() notation meaningless. But generally Hashtbl.add runs in O(1) amortized. Amortized because very now and then the Hashtbl resizes. Inserting n items is best done by setting the initial size larger than n.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `n <= 256` is not true, given that `n` is the length of the input string, which may be longer than 256 characters.

Comment: "If you add the condition that all characters in the string are unique"

Answer (score 0):

Since your table never exceeds around 255 entries, you can reasonably consider the time as being linear in the length of the string.

However, you should realize that if you add a new mapping for an old value to an OCaml hash table, it keeps both entries in the table. This is strange, but OCaml hash tables have always worked this way. You might want to check whether you have an entry in the table before bothering to add a new one.

```
# let h = Hashtbl.create 255;;
val h : ('_a, '_b) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.add h 32 ' ';;
- : unit = ()
# Hashtbl.add h 32 ' ';;
- : unit = ()
# Hashtbl.iter (fun k v -> Printf.printf "saw %d\n" k) h;;
saw 32
saw 32
- : unit = ()
```

As a side comment, I don't see much reason to map from the character code to the character. You can get this without a hash table using `Char.chr`.